# How can I boot from read-only filesystem while having writable partitions for logs?

Tags: boot, filesystem, security

I want to mount my root filesystem as read-only on boot, and use separate writable partition for logs.

Is it necessary to create a ramfs image for such task?

How can I do this?

Comment: In addition to logs, you may need writable `/tmp`, maybe `/home`, some folders in `/var`.

Comment: Read only root filesystem may not work, why would you want to do this?

Comment: why not when live cd's work? knoppix is a good example for what i want to do. unionfs with knoppix do the work great. i just want to do such a work with ubuntu.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, typically you would not want to mount / as read-only. I would recommend putting /usr in it's own partition and then mounting that read-only since it contains the majority of your executable files, which you would want to protect against manipulation of binaries. 
You could also run lsof to determine what processes are writing to the directories under /.

http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/aix/library/au-unmount_partitions/index.html